# Objects in Arrays Help Lua?

Tags: arrays, oop, lua

So, I have an array

```
//loop here
nummobs = nummobs + 1
Mobs = {}
Mobs[nummobs] = Entity.Init(x(locations to spawn mob), y(locations to spawn mob),"testMob")
```

Then, call the draw method...

```
for i = 0, table.getn(Mobs) do
    Mobs[i].draw()
end
```

Error: map.lua:54(Mobs[i].draw() line): attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)... BUT IT HAS SOMETHING IN IT! right?

Anyone ever try something like this? Can anyone fix it?

Thanks

Nate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua uses 1-based indexes for arrays. Thus, the range of an array is `[1, n]` inclusive, where `n` is the number of elements.

More importantly, you can use `ipairs` and not have to write out the loop components:

```
for i, mob in ipairs(Mobs) do
  mob:draw()
end
```

Oh, and never use `getn`; [use the `#` length operator instead](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5).